# Why is hot-ground reading a different voltage from neutral-ground?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I recently replaced a 20a simplex receptacle with a new 20a simplex Decora receptacle.  I checked everything at the new 20a receptacle with a multimeter and here are the results:

Power on

- Hot to neutral = 126.8
- Hot to ground = 128.9
- Ground to neutral = 4.764

Power off

- Hot to neutral = 12.28
- Hot to ground = 11.08
- Ground to neutral = 5.535

Is this a phantom voltage or is this indicative as a loose neutral?

Other things:

- receptacle is self grounding (brass clip on the "tongue," so I removed the insulators from the screws
- receptacle is in a wiremold surface mount box
- there is 14awg THNN running behind the 20a receptacle in raceway to an ungrounded receptacle
- the ungrounded receptacle is on a circuit with four other receptacles and two ceiling fixtures (one pendant, one DC ceiling fan)
- the aforementioned circuit (before the raceway connection) lacks a ground wire but I assume is grounded through conduit because I have verified conduit running behind the plaster with my own eyes (also every other outlet I've checked has an equal reading hot-ground and hot-neutral)

With both of the circuits off, the 20a receptacle reads:

- Hot to neutral = 4.623
- Hot to ground = 4.536
- Ground to neutral = 0.107

The ungrounded outlet reads: 0.034

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Beware: modern day voltmeters can be so sensitive they can read voltages just from wires being next to each other. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hold on, is the ground actually continuous all the way back to the panel??

Comment: Well, it's a sub panel in the condo unit itself. But there is conduit running out of it. All the new wiring (one room only) has ground running to the neutral bar.                                       https://i.redd.it/ddy5m4ztvda31.png

Comment: Oh. Ground and neutral *are* separated. Green wire guy doesn't know where he is,  those should terminate to panel chassis not N.

Comment: Plugging in a resistive load like a heater or incandescent lamp would help eliminate phantom voltage readings since it will absorb that.

Comment: I'm in a condo so there is a main disconnect in the electrical room on my floor.  So I believe bonding ground and neutral at this panel is OK (since the panel is actually the main and not the sub panel as I believed)?  Though I understand that they should be separated as a best practice.

Answer (score -1):

It's strange how these forums meant for getting answers to Qs so rarely just. get. a. direct. answer.

your question:
*"Is this a phantom voltage or is this indicative as a loose neutral?"*

Answer: Most likely just a "phantom" voltage.

More info: There's a lot that could account for those few volts. Most consumer grade meters have some level of error, not much, but enough to contribute to reading a few volts. Most branch circuits deriving from a building power system in a condo complex will have a higher degree of "noise" for lack of [not really lack of, Just no point in getting technical or trying to "flex" as many do on these sites] a better word, moreso say than a single family home. Also branch circuits of long distance from their source of power have what is called voltage drop and this can develop a small usually harmless voltage between the neutral and ground.

TLDR: I would not worry about the readings you're getting at all.